# zsh in vi mode; how to change color scheme?

Tags: zsh

I recently switched from bash to zsh with a custom profile and I use the vim mode. All is working perfectly but I really don't like the color scheme of the selection (mark) mode.

I'd like something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSmNS.jpg

while my current situation is this:

1. [Normal] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTS9o.jpg)
2. [Visual mode on] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWx0R.jpg)
3. [Selection] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEfnj.jpg)

As you can see the selection block is the same color as the background so it's difficult to distinguish and have only a little trait at the top.
I tried to search for the file to edit to change the color scheme but I find only links to themes and mods.

Any help to solve this annoyance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `zle_highlight` array. The following is close to your example. You may want to set other keys in the array such as default: and paste:. Much of the zsh documentation uses the emacs term *region*.

`zle_highlight=( region:bg=229,fg=235 )`

The cursor colour is configured for your terminal emulator rather than under the control of zsh. It is worth taking care over the interaction with your cursor. The cursor position is always part of the selection in vim mode so if both cursor and selection apply reverse video, the effect is useless. It is a good idea to add a hook for `zle-keymap-select()` which swaps the cursor between a block and a bar for normal vs. insert mode. The escape sequences may depend on your terminal emulator but something like:

```
zle-keymap-select() {
  if [[ $KEYMAP = vicmd ]]; then
    print -n '\e[2 q'
  else
    print -n '\e[5 q'
  fi
}
zle-line-init() {
  print -n '\e[5 q'
}
zle -N zle-keymap-select
zle -N zle-line-init
preexec() {
  print -n $'\e[2 q'
}
```

Unfortunately, it is tricky to trap visual mode being enabled but no text selected. The `visual` keymap is never "selected" because it is a local keymap that is overlaid on `vicmd`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the cursor code, though I already have the "change-cursor-shape" code in my zsh config file.